# Как добавить свойство WrapPanel ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" в коде C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как прописать это свойсво в коде
`<WrapPanel ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>`

```cs
WrapPanel a = new WrapPanel();
a.ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = True; // не работает
a.CanContentScroll = True; // не работает
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144494/discussion-on-question-by-----wrappanel-scrollviewer); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollViewer.SetCanContentScroll(myWrapPanel, true)
```